# Sketchup 3d model import with wrong topology?

Tags: mesh, topology

[image]

Imported this 3d Model from google sketchup ,and when i open it with blender or 3Dmax i get those extra lines all over , is there a way to get them deleted ,or remove them with ease ?!?!

Comment: This seems to be triangles (instead of quads). You can Alt+J to make quads from triangles (select the corresponding surfaces before). But consider too that this not a real problem: triangles can stay triangles... very dependent of what you want to do after that.

Comment: What you are seeing are the results of Sketchup being a bad modelling tool topology wise. It creates NGons, bad topology and non-manifold geometry without discretion, and when imported to other proper modelling tools those problems light up. Also as mentioned most exchange formats only support triangles, so anything with more than 3 sides will be decomposed into simpler geometry

Answer (score 2):

Those are the result of triangulating faces, possibly because of the file format used for the exporting (e.g. .3ds will do that regardless whether you asked it to or not).

To get quads-based topology back:

- It should be possible to [convert them back to quads](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/faces.html#triangles-to-quads) with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, but this might not work in all cases (depends on topology complexity). You will need to convert faces which were converted not in desired way manually;
- use another file format for import / export, e.g. .fbx or .dae.

Note: the need in converting depends on the final result you're aiming to.